# Multiple containers in ECS task deinition deployment with github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, github-actions

I have deployed my docker images in ecs cluster from github actions. But the issue is i have created a single task-definition and created multiple containers within. Now through github actions i want to edit the task-def.json with multiple containers an deploy it at once.

I know it is ideal to have single task-def for single container and use github actions but is there anyway so that i can pass multiple images to the task-def and deploy it in 2 steps itself

These are the steps i have been using

```
- name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
  id: task-def
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
  with:
    task-definition: task-definition.json
    container-name: my-container
    image: image_name

- name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
  with:
    task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
    service: my-container-service
    cluster: my-cluster
    wait-for-service-stability: true
```

Any Help is appreciated, To send multiple images at once to the task-def file
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Modify Amazon ECS task definition with second container
  id: render-app-container
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
  with:
    task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
    container-name: app2
    image: amazon/amazon-ecs-sample-2:latest
```